# Annoying intelisense warning in VS Code for Laravel's built in commands

Tags: php, laravel, intelephense

[image: Visual explanation]

The image above is self explanatory, I always get `Undefined method [every built in laravel method]` every time I create a Laravel project. I'm using PHP Intelephense extension to help me with autocompletion and stuffs.

This kind of annoying since they sometimes got mixed with another errors I've made in the project and make it difficult to find where was the real error is.

Also sometimes, I have to deep dive into the `vendor, facades, illuminate, etc` folders to let the IDE scans each files and knows that the class and methods is exist in the project to make the autocompletion works.

I'm using the latest version of VS Code and PHP Intelephense extension. Installing [laravel-ide-helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) does nothing. Is there anything I can do to fix this issue?